# Automated software optimization and tuning

Tags: software, hpc

I'm writing code that uses a lot of graph operations; many higher-level algorithms iterate over all the graph edges and do some processing on them. There's an iterator method that returns a batch of edges, like so:

```
G.get_edges(edges,iterator,num_edges);
for (k = 0; k < num_edges; k++) {
    i = edges[k,0];
    j = edges[k,1];
    // Do something to (i,j)
}
```

Elsewhere in the program, there's a parameter called `batch_size` which is the standard number of edges to operate on whenever this algorithm is called. Currently, I have have `batch_size` hard-coded to 64, figuring that a cache line can hold 128 integers on my computer.

**What's a sane way to automatically tune the batch size?** I'd like to do something akin to how [ATLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatically_Tuned_Linear_Algebra_Software) chooses the block size without having to read the ATLAS source code.

My best guess for how this should work:

1. Compile an initial version of the code where the batch size is chosen at run-time
2. Run a test suite several times with different batch sizes.
3. Pick the batch size `b` for which the test suite ran fastest.
4. Generate a new `.h` file containing a pre-processor directive that sets the batch size to be `b`.
5. Compile the rest of the code, for which the batch size is now known at compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just write an edit, compile, run loop in shell or Python that does it directly in the .h file if you think hard-coding this value is likely to give the compiler an advantage. If the runs are short enough, it ought to be straightforward to iterate over all values of `batch_size` in a reasonable range.

Comment: For larger parameter spaces, you could use a racing approach such as [irace](http://iridia.ulb.ac.be/irace/) or a model-based approach such as [SMAC](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/labs/beta/Projects/SMAC/).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's rather uncommon these days to run an auto-tuning build, but not out of the question.  Looking at your code sample, I don't actually see any cache reuse, so I'm not sure what your anticipated benefit here is.

As Bill alludes, you should probably make the batch size a run-time parameter unless you've got evidence that your compiler is behaving inefficiently without it statically compiled in.